# passing php variable to modal window with click function

Tags: jquery

I have a click function that launches a modal window. Inside of the modal window I load modal_window.php. The click function look like this:

```
$('a#testmodal').click(function(e){
<? $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
varid = <? echo $id; ?>;
        $.get('modal_window.php?id=' + varid, function(data){
modal.open({content: data});});
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

And the link that I'm using to trigger it looks like this:

```
<a id="testmodal" href="modal_2.php?id=5">Test</a>
```

The strange thing is when I click on the link the first time nothing happens. However when I click on it the second time everything works as it should. The reason for this seems to be that the jquery piece of my code runs the first time before the php variable $id is set (the jquery section runs and then the php section runs). Then when I click on the link the second time (the php variable $id within the click function is set at this point) everything works perfectly.

So my question is is there a different way to pass a variable from my link to my click function that does not depend on php. Something like this:

```
<a id="testmodal" href="" var id ="5">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work the first time because there won't be any data on `$_GET` so the function will have a syntax error and the link will act "normally". On second click you will have the `id` parameter so it will open the modal.

Now, I don't quite understand the logic behind your implementation but if you simply want to pass a value to your click handler you could use data attributes:

**HTML**

```
<a id="testmodal" href="#" data-id ="5">Test</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#testmodal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('modal_window.php?id=' + $(this).data('id'), function(data){
        modal.open({content: data});}); 
});
```

That would work, but I assume you'll have multiple links to different modal windows so you may want to give a class to your links and use that as your selector in the click handler, something like:

```
$('.open-modal').click(function(e){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That almost solves the problem. My only issue now is when I have multiple links like this: '<a id="testmodal" href="#" data-id ="5">Test</a>
<a id="testmodal" href="#" data-id ="6">Test</a>' (eventually these links would be generated dynamically within a while loop). Now the first link works but the second one doesn't.

Comment: ids must be unique in your HTML, that's why I suggested using a class instead: `<a class="open-modal" href="#" data-id ="5">Test</a>` and use the class selector as I mentioned above to bind the handlers

Comment: Thanks again. It works perfectly...and thanks for taking the time to explain the class versus ids approach.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs before the client is even sent the data (PHP is run by your server). If you inspect the source, you won't see any

That said, see this question: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).