# Get unique id of iterated ul contents

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am working with PHP in Codeigniter and a fresher too.. I am stuck in a problem for last 2 days.

I have page to show event lists which are fetched from the database and displayed using loop. I've done that successfully. Now i want to give an option to edit or delete individual events which should make db changes. For that i use 2 buttons ; edit and remove. Note all are in a single loop and thus same buttons repeat in every events (item). Once click on a button, it shows a modal. For example, when click on delete button, it shows a modal asking for confirm deletion. DELETE button in that modal submit my form and call controller function that should delete corresponding database entry.

How can i identify the id of that particular item so that i can delete or update it ? I am getting the id of first item always.I referred this : [passing php variable to modal window with click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439354/passing-php-variable-to-modal-window-with-click-function)

But I couldn't link these  and  with my problem

Here is my view:

```
<ul class="timeline">

    <?php  
    if(isset($eventlist)){ 
      foreach ($eventlist as $events) { 
        <li class="yellow timeline-noline' > 
            <div class="timeline-time">
                        <span class="date" id="date" >
                        <?php if(!empty($events->event_date)){echo $events-   >event_date ;} ?> </span>
                                        <span class="time" id="time" >
                                        <?php if(!empty($events->event_time)){echo $events->event_time ;}?> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="timeline-icon">
                                        <i class="icon-trophy" style="margin-top:12px;"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                    <div>
                                    <button type="button" title="Remove" id="remove" name="remove" href="#portlet-remove" data-toggle="modal" style="float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" title="edit" id="edit" name="edit"  href="#portlet-edit"  data-toggle="modal"style="float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                                        <h2 id="title" ><?php if(!empty($events->event_title)){echo $events->event_title ;}?></h2>
                                    </div>

                                        <div class="timeline-content">
                                            <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                        <span id="desc" > <?php if(!empty($events->event_desc)){echo $events->event_desc ;}?>   </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="timeline-footer">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link pull-right">
                                            <!--Read more <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i> -->
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <?php

                            }  }  ?>

                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mark up ID of buttons duplicating. It'll leads to html validation error and if you try to access the button with ID it'll always point to the first element with corresponding ID.

you could use a user defined attribute in your delete button like below and also use class instead of ID.

```
 <button type="button" title="Remove" rel="id for identifying element $i " class="remove" name="remove" href="#portlet-remove" data-toggle="modal" style="float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

Javascript Like this

```
$('body').on('click','.remove',function(){
         var idUnique =   $(this).attr('rel');
         //You could pass this idUnique to controller for deletion.

    //Assign the idUnique to Hidden field inside modal body.
$('#selectedID').val(idUnique );
    });
```

Comment: but i have to show a modal to confirm deletion and button in that modal will submit my form. ie, call controller function.

Comment: not an issue simply place a hidden field for storing selected id inside the modal body. when ever you submit confirm use that id for deletion.

Comment: Thanks..Its Working perfect !! Anyway, am posting the exact working code so that anyone can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using the following code updates :

```
function showmodal(id)
    {
    var eventid=id;
    document.getElementById("hiddenevent").value = eventid;
    $('#portlet-remove').modal('show');
    }
```

and added a hidden input in my modal

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenevent" id="hiddenevent">
```

Updated my 'delete' button as

```
<button type="button" title="Remove" id="remove" name="remove"  onClick="showmodal(<?php echo $events->event_id;?>)" href="" data-toggle="modal" style="float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to clean your code.

```
echo "<ul class='timeline'>\n";
$i=0 ; $k=0;
if (isset($eventlist)) { 
    foreach ($eventlist as $events) { 
        $numb = count($eventlist);
        if($i == 6) { 
            $i=0; 
        }
        if ($k == $numb-1) {
            echo "<li class='".$class_array[$i]." timeline-noline' >\n";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='".$class_array[$i]."'>\n";
        }
        echo "<div class='timeline-time'>\n";
            echo "<span id='date' class='date'>\n";
            if (!empty($events->event_date)) {
                echo $events->event_date;
            }
            echo "</span>\n";
            echo "<span class='time' id='time'>\n";
            if (!empty($events->event_time)) {
                echo $events->event_time;
            }
            echo "</span>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class='timeline-icon'>\n";
            echo "<i class='".$icon_array[$i]."' style='margin-top:12px;'></i>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class='timeline-body'>\n";
            echo "<div>\n";
                echo "<button type='button' title='Remove' id='remove' name='remove' href='#portlet-remove' data-toggle='modal' style='float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>\n";
                echo "<button type='button' title='edit' id='edit' name='edit' href='#portlet-edit' data-toggle='modal' style='float:right;background-color: transparent;border: 0px;'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></button>\n";
                echo "<h2 id='title' >\n";
                    if (!empty($events->event_title)) {
                        echo $events->event_title;
                    }
                echo "</h2>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
            echo "<div class='timeline-content'>\n";
                echo "<img class='timeline-img pull-left' src='".$this->config->base_url()."assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg' alt=''>\n";
                echo "<span id='desc'>\n";
                    if (!empty($events->event_desc)) {
                        echo $events->event_desc;
                    }
                echo "</span>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
            echo "<div class='timeline-footer'>\n";
                echo "<a href='javascript:;' class='nav-link pull-right'>\n";
                echo "<!--Read more <i class='m-icon-swapright m-icon-white'></i> -->\n";
                echo "</a>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";
$i++; $k++; 
    }
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

You had a massive white-space between "?" and ">" on line 14-15.

You seem to be trying to make a *for*-type loop with a *foreach*-type loop. *for* is used when you know how many times the loop will run. *foreach* will loop through an array until the array is empty. If you want to continue to use foreach then there's no reason for you to use these

```
if($i == 6) { }
$i=0; $k=0;
$class_array[$i]
$icon_array[$i]
$i++; $k++;
```

And I'm pretty sure that this...

```
echo $events->event_desc;
```

...will not work, but since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish I won't say anything more.

Comment: if($i == 6) { }
$i=0; $k=0;
$class_array[$i]
$icon_array[$i]
$i++; $k++;

these are not for showing the event list, but using for some other HTML properties of item such as color and tag image.. I updated my Question with relevant code only.. please check